# MemoryError while fitting a sparse matrix to kNN model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, knn

While running the below code I am having a `MemoryError:` from the last line.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7)
clf.fit(train_X, y_train)
y_pred_clf = clf.predict(test_X)
```

The `test_X` is a `<10852x112 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 97668 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way** is to use batches of the data and the **second one** is to use a different algorithm for the KNN model:

```
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,algorithm='kd_tree').fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_pred_clf = clf.predict(test_X)
```

The model by default is algorithm='brute' and brute false take too much memory.